# UK expat bank account

Tags: banking, uk-citizens

How can a UK citizen open a UK bank account without a UK address?  Are there any UK banks which do this? I have recently been told that my UK bank account, used for pension payments, is to be closed because I live in Cyprus.

Comment: Opening a UK bank account requires proof of a UK address.  No exemptions or workarounds.  But a pension can be transferred to Cyprus without problems

Comment: @GayotFow are you sure? When I moved over 6+ years ago HSBC in the US helped me open an account with HSBC UK before I got there.

Comment: Different case.  But you can read the [JMLSG guidance](http://www.jmlsg.org.uk/) and tell me if I'm right or not.  The guidance lists out what a bank needs to see.

Comment: Does it need to be a UK-based bank account? Or would a GBP-denominated one held elsewhere in Europe work?

Comment: Not really an answer and perhaps not ideal but the whole EU (including the UK, even though it does not use the euro) is now part of SEPA so having your pension transferred to an account in Cyprus might be slightly easier than before.

Comment: @Gagravarr, DWP doesn't care what currency the account is denominated in, but the OP may wish to avoid getting whipsawed by exchange rates.

Comment: @GayotFow I'm wondering if a GBP-based account in somewhere like the channel islands, aimed at a non-resident, might be the answer? They'll still do (quite strict) ID checking, but would be perfectly happy with British personal ID + non-British residential ID

Comment: @Gagravarr, same regulator. And they are even worse with section 5.3. It's not going to happen in the Sterling world and that makes the OP's question unanswerable.  The OP needs to change the question.